# Why HashSet of Integers returns false for a Double element?

Tags: java

I created a **HashSet** of **Integers** (Ex. 5). When I try to check the HashSet for the same added element but in a **Double** element version (Ex. 5d, 5.0). It couldn't identify and returns false!

My assumption was, Java would implicitly convert **Double** to **Integer** and try to identify. But it didn't! Why is this the case?

```
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(5);

    System.out.println(set.contains(5d)); // returns false? Why?
    System.out.println(set.contains(5.0));// returns false? Why?
    System.out.println(set.contains(5));  // returns true
    System.out.println(5 == 5d);          // returns true
```

Comment: No it doesn't. The other questions accepted answer says Java does type comparison within HashMap. But I don't see a type comparison done within HashMap containsKey method.

Comment: To put it in terms of the other answer: these cases return `false` because `Integer.valueOf(5).equals(Double.valueOf(5))` is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

[`HashSet.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) takes an `Object` as parameter (so, basically anything). `5.0` is a `double` so it gets autoboxed to a `Double`, and your `HashSet` only contains `Integer` values, which never compare `.equals` to a `Double`.

Even if `HashSet.contains` took an `Integer` as argument, Java would reject your code. In general, Java is pretty stingy about implicit conversions and will only do so if there's no loss of precision. So it will happily convert, say, an `int` to a `long` without asking, but it's way more careful about converting a `double` to an `int` or to an `Integer`.

Comment: so you are saying it will compare the object type first, before comparing the value? which means it will first do something like Double == Integer and it will fail?

Comment: Exactly. `Double.equals` will get called, and the first thing that method does is check the type of the right-hand-side.

Comment: I am respectfully disagreeing to your answer. I did a debug through inside HashSet contains method. I don't see Double.equals getting called.

Comment: It returns false in the below if condition within getNode method in HashMap. 

if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null)

And I don't understand what this means

Comment: @williamcage _"I don't see Double.equals getting called"_ -- that is correct, because it's a `HashSet<Integer>`, thus it will be `Integer#equals()` that is called.  It also checks the type of the other object and returns false if the types are not the same.  For it to work, you MUST pass an `Integer` to the `.contains()` method, which you can get via `doubleVariable.intValue()` (with appropriate truncation if the value is not actually an integer).

Comment: I put a breakpoint in Integer#equals() as well. This method is not getting called.

Comment: @williamcage The "Hash" in HashSet is relevant here. `equals` isn't invoked at all until first the hashes are equal. 5.0D the double has a different hash value than 5, the integer. Hence you never get to `equals` in the first place. `Double.valueOf(5.0D).hashCode()` and `Integer.valueOf(5).hashCode()` - compare those.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thanks. this is the sort of direction I am looking. But, how is this hash comparison done? It is failing in this condition  if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 && (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) within HashMap. How is this relating to the hash comparison?

Comment: @william The hash is used to index into the "table" (i.e. array). That's typical hash table stuff. If it doesn't find anything in the "bucket" then it knows immediately it does not contain the element. If there _is_ something in the bucket then it will compare the objects via `equals`. Note that Java's `HashSet` handles hash collisions by using a linked list, until a certain threshold is reached, where it changes over to a tree structure.